# How to solve: socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

```
import smtplib

my_email = "NAME@gmail.com"
password = "PASSWORD"

receiver = "NAME@yahoo.com"

connection = smtplib.SMTP("smpt.gmail.com")
connection.starttls()
connection.login(user=my_email, password=password)
connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_email, to_addrs=receiver, msg="hello matafakha")
connection.close()
```

this is a code that i wanted to test, i am new to python and working with the smptlib, how do i solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

> connection = smtplib.SMTP("smpt.gmail.com")

You have a typo here. It should be:

```
connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com")
```